# Conversion by constructor doesn't work with operator overloading

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

Consider the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

class complex
{
private:
    double re,im;
public:
    complex(double, double);
    complex(double);
    complex operator+(complex c);
    double getre();
    double getim();
};

complex complex::operator+(complex c)
{
    return *new complex(re+c.getre(),im+c.getim());
}

complex::complex(double real, double imagine)
{
    re= real;
    im= imagine;
}

complex::complex(double real)
{
    re= real;
    im=0;
}

double complex::getre()
{
    return re;
}

double complex::getim()
{
    return im;
}

int main()
{
    complex *z= new complex(2.0);
    complex *w= new complex(3.0, 4.0);
    printf("%f\n",(2.0+*z).getre());//Compile error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘2.0e+0 + * z’

}
```

But if we replaced our operator member function to a non-member function like the following:

```
complex operator+(complex t, complex c)
{
    return *new complex(t.getre()+c.getre(),t.getim()+c.getim());
}
```

then it works fine. But I'm expected that it will work in all descibed cases. We've defined constructor conversion as.

Comment: `return *new complex` O_o... that will leak memory every time it is called!

Comment: Exactly that is the reason why you would write a free op+

Comment: Your expectation is wrong, the recommended practice is to write a free function instead of a member for exactly this reason.

Comment: None of this code has any reason to use `new` at all.

Comment: @Dmitrii - By any chance, are you a Java coder?  Your usage of `new` suggests such.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I'm Java coder.

Comment: @Dmitrii- Bingo!!  That explains it.  You know that your code is leaking memory all over the place.  The `new` in C++ is not the same as `new` in Java.

Comment: @Jon I've conviced that my expectation is wrong when I've running this  programm

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, I've understood you. But what about my question? Can you answer me?

Comment: Remember also that C++11 brings you complex numbers as part of the standard library; reinventing the wheel is undesirable even when you're familiar with the language. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

Comment: @Rook I'm just experimenting with operator overloading. Now I'm trying to understand why when I've defined operator overload as a member function the conversion by constructor doesnt work.

Comment: Klaus has it. With an operator overload as a member function, argument order matters. Rewriting the offending line to `(*z + 2.0).getre()` works just fine, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary operators don't attempt any conversion to the left side argument, the "receiver" of the function.
If you want a builtin type on the left hand side, the overload *must* be a free function.

The simplest way is usually to have a mutating member, `+=` in this case, and delegate to that from the free function(s).

Something like this:

```
complex complex::operator+=(complex rhs)
{
    re += rhs.re;
    im += rhs.im;
    return *this;
}

complex operator+(complex t, complex c)
{
    t += c;
    return t;
}    

int main()
{
    complex z(2.0);
    complex w(3.0, 4.0);
    printf("%f\n",(2.0 + z).getre());
}
```

You should also make your getters `const`.

And you receive a gold star for not having setters.

Comment: What's wrong with I have no setters?

Comment: @Dmitrii Gold stars are good, so there's absolutely nothing wrong with that.